# this.setState not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, web

I'm trying to take the inputs using a form and update the state when the checkbox is clicked but for some reason, the state doesn't update. It doesn't throw any error. I searched on google for answers but none of them were plausible.

My code:

```
class PatientForm extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            patientName: "",
            age: null,
            sex: "",
            email: "",
            phoneNo: null
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log(this.state);
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });

        alert(this.state.patientName);
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Jumbotron>
                <h3 className="display-5">Enter Patient info</h3>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        We'll never share your details with anyone else.
                    </Form.Text>
                    <Form.Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control name="patientName" type="text" placeholder="Patient name" required/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control name="age" type="number" placeholder="Patient Age" required/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control name="sex" type="text" placeholder="Patient Sex" required/>
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <br />
                    <Form.Group>                        
                        <Form.Control  name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" required/>    
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>                        
                        <Form.Control  name="phoneNo" type="number" placeholder="Phone number" required/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.File />
                    <Form.Label>Patient's Eth Address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        ################
                    </Form.Text>
                    <Form.Group >                        
                        <Form.Check 
                            type="checkbox" 
                            label="Tick if the entered info is correct" 
                            onClick = {this.handleSubmit}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={ () => console.log(this.state)}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form>
                <p>{this.state.patientName}</p>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PatientForm;
```

Here the handleSubmit function is revoked when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Can you give me the value of console.log(target.name) in your handleSubmit function?

Comment: console.log(target.name) gives the name attribute of all the input boxes that we have, in our case it logs patientName, age, sex, email, and phoneNo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `handleSubmit` function to `onChange` event of every `<Form.Control />` you want to use to update the state properties.

Read the ["Handling Multiple Inputs"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) documentation page for more insights.

Here is how you should write you `<PatientForm />` (I renamed `handleSubmit` to `handleChange` and provide new implementation of `handleSumbit`):

```
class PatientForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      patientName: "",
      age: null,
      sex: "",
      email: "",
      phoneNo: null
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // e.g.: send to remote API
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("state", this.state);
    console.log("data sent to remote API");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Jumbotron>
          <h3 className="display-5">Enter Patient info</h3>
          <Form>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              We'll never share your details with anyone else.
            </Form.Text>
            <Form.Row>
              <Col>
                <Form.Control
                  name="patientName"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Patient name"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Form.Control
                  name="age"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Patient Age"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Form.Control
                  name="sex"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Patient Sex"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Row>
            <br />
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control
                name="email"
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control
                name="phoneNo"
                type="number"
                placeholder="Phone number"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.File />
            <Form.Label>Patient's Eth Address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">################</Form.Text>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Check
                type="checkbox"
                label="Tick if the entered info is correct"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
          <p>{this.state.patientName}</p>
        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```